# Python : want to use the command line argument passed in python, as an argument to another command that will be executed within the python script

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script where in the argument that is passed to this script, needs to be used as an argument to a command that will be executed in this script.
Executing this script on cygwin

eg:-
 x.py file1

inside x.py script:

```
file = sys.argv[1]

data = os.popen('ar t file').read()
```

when this command is executed the value of file is not taken(i.e file1),rather the 'file' variable is being considered as a file, and hence throws an error:filename 'file' cannot be found.Is it possible to pass the value of file as an argument to this command.

Thanks,
Akhilesh

Comment: I think it should be `data = os.popen('ar t "%s"' % file).read()` since `file` is a variable that has a string. Also note `""` around to handle filenames with spaces

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with command arguments or passing them on, but a basic misunderstanding of strings. You have a hard-coded string containing the word "file", you are not actually passing in the value of the `file` variable anywhere. You can use string substitution:

```
data = os.popen('ar t {}'.format(file)).read()
```

or

```
data = os.popen('ar t %s' % file).read()
```

Comment: Would this handle "My New File.txt"? I think you need the quotes (around `%s` or `{}` )... Other than that it should work.

Comment: Good point, but that is a separate issue. Actually OP should not be using `os.popen` at all, but `suprocess.call`,

Comment: data = os.popen('ar t %s' % file).read() this worked, but data = os.popen('ar t {}'.format(file)).read() threw an error "zero length filed name in format"